# htaccess: URL with any URI not redirecting to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, https

Currently, this is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

    # Custom Redirects
    Redirect /investors/reporting/estma /investors/investor-reporting/financial-information#estma
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal\.arcresources\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www\.arcresources\.com/portals [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

The redirect works fine if you just type the domain, so arcresources.com properly redirects to https://www.arcresources.com. It also works if you include www and any URI, so www.arcresources.com/investors redirects correctly as well.

The problem is typing just the domain + a URI, so arcresources.com/investors redirects to only https://arcresources.com/investors (no www.), resulting in a connection refusal.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but all my attempts so far have either added double "www"s or resulted in too many redirects.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect HTTP with www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Redirect HTTP without www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Redirect HTTPS without www to HTTPS with www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php  [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Test it in a fresh browser in in-cognito mode.

Comment: Strangely, that redirects  to https:// www. www. arcresources.com. The client is in control of the DNS and domain, so I'm not sure what exactly is going on there. Is there some way to make my original Rewrite work? It seems to be the only one that doesn't mess things up

Comment: Added it to my original "# Redirect to HTTPS" code? No, I haven't. Since it works for everything except "arcresource.com/some-uri", I haven't messed with it.

Comment: That's giving me the error: "www.arcresources.com redirected you too many times"

Comment: I've added a stricter, more verbose version.

Comment: Strange... it makes the URL correct on all accounts, but still has the redirect error.